# SQLHelper Class - Insert/Update method return inserted ID @@identity

Tags: c#

I have an SQL helper  Class for my application, everything works nice as it should be, but in some code, I need to get the inserted ID using @@identity, what is the best way to do this ??

Here is My method in my SQL helper class :

```
public static void InsertUpdate_Data(string sql, CommandType cmdType, params SqlParameter[] parameters)
        {
            using (SqlConnection connStr = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString))
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, connStr))
            {
                cmd.CommandType = cmdType;
                cmd.Parameters.AddRange(parameters);
                try
                {
                    cmd.Connection.Open();
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }
                catch (SqlException ex)
                {
                    //log to a file or Throw a message ex.Message;
                    MessageBox.Show("Error: " + ex.Message);
                }
            }
        }
```

And this is how I use it :

```
DBConn.InsertUpdate_Data("customer_add", CommandType.StoredProcedure,
               new SqlParameter[]
               {
                new SqlParameter("@name", txt_name.Text.Trim()),
                new SqlParameter("@gender", Gender_comb.Text),
                new SqlParameter("@b_o_date", DOBTimePicker1.Value ),
                new SqlParameter("@phone", Phone_txt.Text.Trim()),
                new SqlParameter("@address", string.IsNullOrEmpty(Location_txt.Text) ? (object)DBNull.Value : Location_txt.Text.Trim()),
                new SqlParameter("@note", string.IsNullOrEmpty(Note_txt.Text) ? (object)DBNull.Value : Note_txt.Text.Trim())
               }
```

And also what is the best way to use SQL transactions in some code.

Thank you.

Comment: Modify your sproc to return the ID, then use `cmd.ExecuteScalar()`.

Comment: Best way to use Sql Transactions, should be a separate question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use `@@IDENTITY`, [it's unreliable](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwi5xZ3488nuAhWTTsAKHRkwAm0QFjAAegQIAhAC&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.red-gate.com%2Fhub%2Fproduct-learning%2Fsql-prompt%2Fwhy-you-should-avoid-using-the-identity-function&usg=AOvVaw1P4pjgi3lDERYLg1c4tf9g).

The stored procedure should have, on the line **immediately following** the insert, `SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY()`. Then you can use `cmd.ExecuteScalar` as mentioned.

---

For transactions, you have two options.

Either use `conn.BeginTransaction()` and don't forget to open the connection first, add transaction to `command.Transaction`, and put the transaction in a `using` block:

```cs
public static int InsertUpdate_Data(string sql, CommandType cmdType, params SqlParameter[] parameters)
        {
            try
            {
                using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString))
                {
                    conn.Open()
                    using (var tran = conn.BeginTransaction())
                    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, connStr, tran))
                    {
                        cmd.CommandType = cmdType;
                        cmd.Parameters.AddRange(parameters);
                        var result = (int)cmd.ExecuteScalar();
                        tran.Commit();
                        return result;
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (SqlException ex)
            {
                //log to a file or Throw a message ex.Message;
                MessageBox.Show("Error: " + ex.Message);
                throw;
            }
        }
```

The other, possibly better, option is to use `BEGIN TRANSACTION;` and `COMMIT TRANSACTION;` in the procedure. Don't bother with `TRY/CATCH/ROLLBACK`, just put at the top of the procedure `SET XACT_ABORT ON;`, this guarantees a rollback on the event of an error.

---

Other notes:

1. Use proper types, length and precision on your `SqlParameter`s, it will help with performance.
2. Do **not** block the thread with things like `MessageBox` while the connection is open. Log the exception and check it after. Or better, do what I did above and `try/catch` **around** the connection.

Comment: I'm getting -1 as a return value.

Comment: Are you using `ExecuteScalar` like I said or are you still using `ExecuteNonQuery`?

Comment: I'm using the same method you provided so the method using `(int)cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();`

Comment: Sorry my bad copy pasta, fixed now

Comment: Here is my procedure  : 
`-- Insert statements for procedure here
 INSERT INTO dbo.entrance_testing (n_va_od,n_va_os,n_va_ou,ou_va,ou_va_2,n_eom,n_ct_n,n_ct_d,n_npc) VALUES 
 (@n_va_od,@n_va_os,@n_va_ou,@ou_va,@ou_va_2,@n_eom,@n_ct_n,@n_ct_d,@n_npc); select SCOPE_IDENTITY();`

Comment: I have this error now `'Specified cast is not valid.'`

Comment: Try `SELECT CAST(SCOPE_IDENTITY() AS int);`

Comment: I change it to `var result = Convert.ToInt32(cmd.ExecuteScalar());` and its working now. Thank you so much

Comment: what if I want to call more than one `InsertUpdate_Data()` in the same button how can I roll back the transaction on errors ??

Comment: An exception being thrown will cause the `Transaction` object to be disposed without a `Commit` which will cause a rollback